# Count memberships by type for a series of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and have a database containing membership information. I'm trying to write SQL that will count the members of each type that exist during each month so I can report on if membership is going up/down month by month. A simplified version of my schema is:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fed2/1

```
CREATE TABLE MemberType
(
    MemberTypeID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Invoice
(
    InvoiceID INT,
    DateStart DATE,
    DateEnd   DATE,
    PersonID  INT,     --(FK) Person that purchased the membership
    MemberTypeID INT,  --(FK) Type of membership
);

INSERT MemberType (MemberTypeID,Name) VALUES (1,'Regular')
INSERT MemberType (MemberTypeID,Name) VALUES (2,'Special')
INSERT MemberType (MemberTypeID,Name) VALUES (3,'Honorary')

INSERT Person (PersonID,Name) VALUES (1,'Joe Smith')
INSERT Person (PersonID,Name) VALUES (2,'Anna Smith')
INSERT Person (PersonID,Name) VALUES (3,'Ted Williams')
INSERT Person (PersonID,Name) VALUES (4,'Bill Williams')

INSERT Invoice VALUES(1,'2011-5-1', '2012-1-1', 1, 1)
INSERT Invoice VALUES(2,'2010-1-1', '2013-1-1', 2, 2)
INSERT Invoice VALUES(3,'2012-2-1', '2013-2-1', 3, 1)
INSERT Invoice VALUES(4,'2009-1-1', '2011-5-1', 1, 1)
INSERT Invoice VALUES(5,'2011-1-1', '2012-5-1', 4, 1)
```

**I've tried to get the member counts for a specific date like this:**

```
DECLARE @RunDt DATE='2011-1-1'

SELECT
mt.Name [MemberType], @RunDt [Date], count(p.PersonID) [Count]
FROM MemberType mt
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice i ON i.MemberTypeID=mt.MemberTypeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person p ON p.PersonID=i.PersonID
WHERE @RunDt BETWEEN i.DateStart AND i.DateEnd
GROUP BY mt.Name
```

I think this is close but I want the honorary type to be included with a count of 0. I thought the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s would accomplish that, but thy do not.
Also this is only for a single date. My next step is to get the results of that query for the 1st of each month all together in a single result set.

Comment: `COUNT` counts non-NULL values only

Comment: That may be OK since I don't want the NULL values increasing the count. I do want a record returned for each membertype though even if count=0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By placing the filter criteria for the `Invoice` table in the `WHERE` clause, you've essentially converted your `OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. Try putting that filter criteria in the `ON` criteria for the `OUTER JOIN` against `Invoice`.

```
SELECT 
  mt.Name AS [MemberType], 
  @RunDt AS [Date], 
  count(p.PersonID) AS [Count]
FROM dbo.MemberType AS mt
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Invoice AS i 
  ON i.MemberTypeID=mt.MemberTypeID
  AND @RunDt BETWEEN i.DateStart AND i.DateEnd
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Person AS p 
  ON p.PersonID = i.PersonID
GROUP BY mt.Name;
```

Demo:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fed2/2

---

If you want to do this for every month in a given year:

```
DECLARE @year INT = 2012;

;WITH x(d) AS 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MONTH, n-1, 
      DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, '19000101')))
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT TOP (12) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (ORDER BY [object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects 
      ORDER BY [object_id]
    ) AS y
)
SELECT
    mt.[Name],
    [Date] = x.d, 
    [Count] = COUNT(p.PersonID)
FROM x CROSS JOIN dbo.MemberType AS mt
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Invoice AS i 
ON i.MemberTypeID = mt.MemberTypeID
AND x.d BETWEEN i.DateStart AND i.DateEnd
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Person AS p 
ON p.PersonID = i.PersonID
GROUP BY mt.Name, x.d
ORDER BY x.d, mt.Name;
```

SQLFiddle demo:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5f84/2

More info on generating sets without loops:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1
http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2
http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Comment: Ahh, thank you! My goal is to write a report that shows what the counts were on the 1st of each month from Jan-Dec of 2011. Is the best way to do that just looping over this query for each of the 12 dates or is there a better way you know of?

Comment: Really awesome, Aaron. Thanks for sharing your expertise.